# Labor preferences not showing in Dwarf Fortress?

Tags: dwarf-fortress

I have a large abundance of farmers which aren't really needed, so I'd like to switch them to things I'd find more useful. However, I'm not really sure where to do this. Googling the issue told me to select a dwarf and press 'p' for labor settings, but that option **is not present.** Here's a screen-shot of my dwarf's selection screen:
[image: Dwarf Selection Screen]

I'm not really sure what to do at this point, as I've got an enormous amount of food but all of my other endeavors are proceeding very slowly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you select a dwarf in the (u)nit list, you must use zoom-cre(c). This will center the screen on the dwarf in question, and allow you to the it's status(z), (w)ounds, his (i)ventory and, what you're searching for, his (p)references. There, you can change his work preference.

You can also view this screen by pressing (v) in the main screen, and move the cursor to the dwarf you want to view.

[image: Unit List]

[image: Unit View]

Comment: Ah, you were right, only it was Zoom-cre. Thank you!

Comment: After playing DF for 2 years, I've memorized all the key strokes without realizing it. :)

Answer (score 5):

@Jupotter's answer is totally correct, but a MUCH better idea is to get [Dwarf Therapist](http://www.bay12forums.com/smf/index.php?topic=66525.0), especially if you have a bunch of dwarves to deal with. 2-3 isn't too bad w/ the ingame interface, but once you have 100+ dwarves managing the labor for all of them is much easier with DT.

Comment: Once you have 20+ dwarfs, life is hell.

Comment: Yeah, you pretty much need DT after a while.